# how to change RGB to BGR

Tags: c, bitmap, jpeg, rgb, libjpeg

I am using libjpeg to decode a jpeg file and write it to a bitmap file.
When I wrote the decompressed raw image to a file, the colors seem incorrect. For example, color blue turns to purple, green to orange.

Here's the link to my sample jpeg:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3ob0t07z5xEV3hCb0FPQm1ETk0/view?usp=sharing

Here's the original JPEG image:

[image: original JPEG image]

Here's the image converted from JPEG to BMP

[image: jpeg to bitmap image]

Upon searching for solutions on Google, I stumbled upon a few suggestions to convert the image from RGB to BGR. I'm not such an expert on images, but is this the correct solution for my problem?

If so, does libjpeg support RGB to BGR conversion? Here's my code snippet below:

```
struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;
unsigned int bytesPerRow = cinfo.output_width * cinfo.num_components;
unsigned char *raw_image;
JSAMPROW row_pointer[1];
int iCount = 0;
unsigned int totalBytes = cinfo.output_width * cinfo.output_height
            * cinfo.num_components;
unsigned long location = totalBytes;
FILE *bmpFile;

while (cinfo.output_scanline < cinfo.image_height) {
    jpeg_read_scanlines(&cinfo, row_pointer, 1);

    for (iCount = bytesPerRow - 1; iCount <= cinfo.image_width * cinfo.num_components; iCount--) {
        raw_image[location--] = row_pointer[0][iCount];
    }
}

/* need to convert RGB to BGR here before writing to file */

fwrite(raw_image, 1, totalBytes, bmpFile);
```

Code below shows my pallete for COLORED images. The first byte represents the blue part, the second the green and the third the redpart.(I'm not sure about this, I commented this in my code)

```
unsigned long long_val;
unsigned char padding;

padding = 0;

long_val = 2;
fwrite(&long_val, 1, 1, bmpFile);
long_val = 1;
fwrite(&long_val, 1, 1, bmpFile);
long_val = 0;
fwrite(&long_val, 1, 1, bmpFile);

fwrite(&padding, 1, 1, bmpFile);
```

Comment: Maybe you should ask yourself what is RGB and what is BGR and try to answer the question yourself. Also, post pictures of the wrong colors to prove that this is the right thing to be worried about.

Comment: "is this the correct solution for my problem" – well, does it lead to the desired result? If so, then you don't need to ask. If not, please state what is wrong. (My *guess* is that the code indeed converts the RGB order but also mirrors the image.) However: changing just the order would **not** change blue to purple (it would become red) and most certainly not green to orange (it would stay green ...).

Comment: what format is the output file supposed to be?  Just raw bytes with no header?  Oh, and why are you writing the bytes into the array in reverse order?

Comment: Be sure that the problem is actually the YCbCr to RGB conversion and not that the JPEG is being decoded so that the YCbCr components are coming out in the wrong order.

Comment: @MarkLakata Yes, I did. Already updated my question showing the pictures. Jongware, I'm not sure what exactly do you mean by "the code indeed converts the RGB order but also mirrors the image." Sorry. Alnitak, The output should be a bitmap file. I didn't include the code in setting up the bitmap header. The bytes are in reverse order so that the image would be displayed correctly except for the image color, which is the problem I am trying to resolve in this question. If the bytes are in the normal order the image displayed is rotated from bottom to top

Comment: @Marss see my new answer - your file is being rendered in GRB order, but it's probably the fault of your bitmap header.  Please post the code that generates that.

Comment: Your code reverses an entire row from last byte to first, so that's why I guessed it would mirror the image. If that doesn't happen then it must be due to the way the data got stored in the first place. ".. image displayed is rotated from bottom to top" -> please check the BMP specifications for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RGB to BGR conversion is a simple matter of swapping bytes around within a machine word.  You need to do something like this:

```
int i;
char temp;
for( i = 0;  i < raw_image_size;  i += 3 )
{
    //swap R and B; raw_image[i + 1] is G, so it stays where it is.
    temp = raw_image[i + 0];
    raw_image[i + 0] = raw_image[i + 2];
    raw_image[i + 2] = temp;
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer.  This should be a comment.

Comment: @J... I think it is an answer.  It says "RGB to BGR conversion is a simple matter of swapping bytes around within a machine word."

Comment: Every programming problem is solved through a simple matter of swapping bytes around.  Tautology does not an answer make.

Comment: Sorry, updated my question already showing the type of variables and with the proper formatting. I couldn't see why my for loop won't work.

Comment: @J... yes, every programming problem is solved by swapping bytes around, but is every programming problem solved by swapping bytes around *within a machine word?*

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried your snippet, colors are still swapped & incorrect. I will try to figure this out by swapping bytes around

Comment: The answer should have at least correct code. This doesn't swap bytes, because the statements inside the for loop are sequential, not parallel.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen wow, I am sorry, I must have been very sleepy when I was writing that code!  Will fix now.  (Blush)

Comment: Nevertheless, Jongware's comment on the question is relevant - if the OP is getting orange instead of green and purple instead of blue then this is _not_ just an RGB to BGR conversion issue.

Comment: @Alnitak you are most probably right. (Though beware of subjective human perception and description of color.)  But the OP wanted RGB swapping, so I gave him RGB swapping.  If someone else shows up suggesting some other flaw in the OP's approach, their answer will be "more usefull" than mine, so it should be upvoted more.  But as my answer stands now, (eventually,) it is also useful, so it does not deserve to be downvoted.

Comment: @MikeNakis ...and I retracted mine when you improved the answer

Comment: This is the correct answer to my problem. I just made some modifications because the bytes are in BGR order. I swapped G and R, then the colors displayed correctly. I wouldn't have realized this if @Alnitak haven't mentioned in his answer that the red and green components are swapped. Thanks to everyone who have helped me in anyway. I appreciate your effort.

Comment: @Marss did you actually look at the DIB header as I suggested?   That's where you have the option yourself of specifying the RGB order, and if the colours were coming out wrong then just fixing the header should be sufficient without reordering the bytes.

Comment: @Alnitak I actually looked at the BITMAPFILEHEADER and BITMAPINFOHEADER. Please check code above for for my color palette

Comment: @Marrs assuming you have the compression field of the BITMAPINFOHEADER set to `BI_BITFIELDS`, then to specify RGB order you should follow the DIB Header with the three DWORDS `0x00ff0000`, `0x0000ff00`, `0x000000ff`.

Comment: @Alnitak I have the compression field set to 0(no compression).

Comment: @Marss if you like, post your whole code somewhere and I'll take a look and see if it's possible to get a correct BMP file _without_ mangling the RGB byte order.

Comment: @Alnitak Thank you so much for being so helpful. Here are the links to my source files: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3ob0t07z5xEcnJ1d2k2aFN6OTQ/view?usp=sharing https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3ob0t07z5xEQlozaVlMMktodnc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I took a quick look, but it looks like you'd have to move to the 52 byte BITMAPV2INFOHEADER instead of your existing 40 byte BITMAPINFOHEADER

Answer (score 1):

Having now looked at the colours in your posted images in the edited question, I can see that the problem is actually that the red and green components are swapped - the blue component is fine.

The original description was a little misleading, because what you had described as "blue" and "green" were actually closer to "cyan" and a "yellow green".  A pure "blue" can't become purple simply by byte swapping because magenta is a mix of blue and red.   However cyan is a mix of blue and green, but when the green is swapped with red you do indeed get a purplish colour.

I believe it's possible to correct this by putting the correct values in the BMP file's DIB header "bitmask" fields (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format).  Those fields indicate the byte order of the data within the file.